# How does the varchar(limit) work?

Tags: mysql, sql, varchar

I've been working with MySQL and very vaguely understand the `VARCHAR(This Number Here)` part. Is that number the total amount of characters the column can store?

For instance, lets say i have a `VARCHAR(400) latin1_general_ci`, does the 400 mean a 400 byte limit on the string, or that the string can have 400 characters? How big of a string can i store in that column variable?

Comment: It is the character limit, not the byte limit; strings encoded with "bigger" character sets take up more space. This becomes apparent if you run query like `SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the maximum string length of the field (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html)) (NOT bytes):

> The `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` types are declared with a length that indicates the maximum number of characters you want to store. For example, `CHAR(30)` can hold up to 30 characters.

This will allow 30 characters regardless of the encoding.

> Values in `VARCHAR` columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 65,535. The effective maximum length of a `VARCHAR` is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used.
>
> In contrast to `CHAR`, `VARCHAR` values are stored as a 1-byte or 2-byte length prefix plus data. The length prefix indicates the number of bytes in the value. A column uses one length byte if values require no more than 255 bytes, two length bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes.